# php table not displaying contents and only creating table boxes

Tags: php

I would like the table to display all the values inside of it, but it is currently not displaying the values and only creating an empty table

[what the table is displayed as (image)][1]

```
$result = mysqli_query( $conn,'SELECT * FROM Pictures ');
$conn->close();
```

Html

```
<html>

<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;"  

    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>image</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
if( $result != null){
```

Result is not empty

```
    while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        foreach ($row1 as $row){

            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php $row['hname'] ?></td>
                <td><?php $row['himage'] ?></td>
                <td><?php $row['hdesc'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
   }else{
    echo "Something went wrong with the result";
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <?php //mysqli_close($conn); ?>
 </body>


 </html>
```

changed the out put to match the answer you gave but the output came out as picture 2 while my table is actually picture 3 any ideas
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC6wz.jpg):

[table im trying to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE98b.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried using <?=$row['id'] ?> to indicate you actually want to print it? You could also use "echo" or "print". Just entering a variable name doesn't mean you want to print it..

Comment: Why are you creating a `foreach` loop? There's no need for that.

Comment: You simply missing `echo` function: `<td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
   <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
   <td><?php $row['hname'] ?></td>
   <td><?php $row['himage'] ?></td>
   <td><?php $row['hdesc'] ?></td>
```

to

```
   <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['hname']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['himage']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['hdesc']; ?></td>
```

or the shorthand variant

```
   <td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?= $row['hname']; ?></td>
   <td><?= $row['himage']; ?></td>
   <td><?= $row['hdesc']; ?></td>
```

And as Samuel pointed out in a comment, are you sure there is a need for the extra `foreach` considering you're already looping with the `while`?

**Update:** OP have you tried the following?

```
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
  //removed foreach()
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['himage']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hdesc']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
   }else{
```

**Update 2** OP wishes to have the image load instead of showing the raw URL.
To do this, we need to use an actual image tag and insert the url into the `src`.

I assume that this line is the image URL

`<td><?php echo $row['himage']; ?></td>`

So change it to

`<td> <img src="<?php echo $row['himage']; ?>" > </td>`

Comment: @ProEvils i edited my code to match the echo solution you gave but im getting a different output from whats im my table, ive added new screenshots to the question

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm check my answer again

Comment: yeah that worked thanks, i upvoted you but im too low a level for it to count

Comment: its only showing the web address for the pictures, do you know hoe to make it so it will load the actual image?, thanks

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm Yes, see my updated answer again

Answer (score 2):

Display the data in this way:

```
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
```